# How to retrieve all the expressions NOT following a specific format

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and I need to search for all the `return` expressions which do *not* follow this format for their brackets:

```
return (SomeObject);
```

For example, I need to find statements like this:

```
return objItem;
```

I tried the following as the search expression with enabling "use regular expressions" but it does not find them:

```
return (?!()
```

Could someone explain why this doesn't work and/or suggest an improvement/alternative to my regex?

Comment: "*but it does not work*" - what does that regex find?

Comment: It doesn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
return [^(].*;
```

This finds lines like:

```
return something;
return func(x);
```

But not

```
return (foo);
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/omFIqLWthH)

Comment: It will also capture `return View(intval);`. No idea if that is what you want. I have suggested using a check if `return` is immediately followed by a parenthetical construction.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `return (?!()` is not valid since the `(` symbolmust be escaped inside the negative lookbehind `(?!\()`. However, this will just match `return`.

If you need to capture all "return"s with no parentheses after it, you can use

```
\s*return\s+[^()]+;
```

Or, you can use a negative look-ahead checking that there is no `xxx (yyy)` string after it:

```
(?!return\s*\([^)]+?\)\s*;)\s*return\s+[^;]+;
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f!return%5cs*%5c(%5b%5e)%5d%2b%3f%5c)%5cs*%3b)%5cs*return%5cs%2b%5b%5e%3b%5d%2b%3b&i=return+(SomeObject)%3b%0d%0areturn+objItem%3b%0d%0areturn+View()%3b)

Comment: I tried it but still does not find anything! I do have something like this : 
return View();

Comment: but it found this : return View;   which does not work for me because I need to find the returns that are not followed by brackets.

Comment: Thanks stribizhev! this also works! However, it finds the expressions three times as it matches with its tab spaces in each search.